# Please tell me how to fix this rigging problem

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have a problem with rigging the imported model. Here is a screenshot of my object, you can see the arm deformation. In the second picture, you can see that the mesh is tilted. Could somebody please tell me the cause of this problem? It is embarrassing but I am totally newbie in 3D modeling so I have no idea what to do.[[image]]

[image]

Comment: You should really begin with something simpler if you are a newcomer to Blender and 3D. This model lacks proper skinning and the instructions about how to fix it would be a lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

[This model](https://p3dm.ru/files/characters/supernatural/9345-hibana.html) is very complex and requires manual weights editing. [The automatic weights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7piAUK9AQs4) or [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/) could only be a starting point.

[image]

The model is ripped with losses. There is no material data, and it's probably missing a small part and a vertex color data. This kind of game model demands deep 3D knowledge.

[image]

I made a rigging with Mixamo and tried to set up materials. I have not figured out how exactly those alpha maps are used, but overall it is correct. The weights still need attention.

[image]

[image]

A small tip I have learned: by default, Blender ignores color data for pixels with zero alpha, and you need to set Alpha from Straight to Channel Packed so it will not affect RGB value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: While this is a very thorough answer it ignores the original question completely.